# Probability help needed

Tags: r, probability

I have a R data frame (>2000 obs)

```
       Date meanLVL.QLD meanLVL.VIC
1 1990-01-02       1.194       0.721
2 1990-01-03       1.192       0.715
3 1990-01-04       1.196       0.708
4 1990-01-05       1.206       0.703
5 1990-01-06       1.200       0.708
6 1990-01-07       1.200       0.701
```

How can I calculate probability that the `meanLVL.QLD` is higher than the `meanLVL.VIC` if randomly selects one of the dates from these dataset?
and the probability that between 200 and 500 (inclusive) of the dates, `meanLVL.QLD` to be higher than `meanLVL.VIC`? Any assumptions required?

Comment: Are these measurements of the same thing repeatedly over time? If so, you'll need to take their nonindependence into account.

Comment: These are measurements taken by two instruments of the same thing repeatedly over time

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to test if one is higher.

1. assume that both of your variables are normally distributed (you can test this assumption using a normality test), and do a one-tailed paired $t$ test.  This tests for the difference in means, so $\mu_{QIC}>\mu_{VIC}$.

   do this using `t.test(meanLVL.QLD,meanLVL.VIC,paired=TRUE, alternative = "greater")`
2. You can do a one-tailed non-parametric test (Wilcoxon signed-rank test), but you will be testing the hypothesis that the mean difference of ranks is higher for QIC than VIC and not exactly that the mean on QIC is higher. However, you do not have to assume a particular distribution for your data so there are fewer assumptions.

The probability that you will draw a date with meanLVL.QLD > meanLVL.VLC from your database is equal to the number of cases where this is true devided by the number $N$ of dates in your dataset.

As for the last step I'm guessing you want to know the probability that you got between 200 and 500 cases by chance alone (choose $p = .5$), or that you will get that in a future dataset with N cases (choose $p$ calculated  above). You can check the probability that the number $X$ out of $N$ dates of meanLVL.QLD > meanLVL.VIC will will be between 200 and 500 assuming that in the true probability of that happening on any one date is p by using the binomial distribution:

$$ Pr(200\leq X\leq 500) = \sum_{i = 200}^{500} \binom{N}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{N-i}$$

you can do this by using the cumulative binomial function in R: `pbinom(500, size=N, prob=p) -pbinom(199, size=N, prob=p)` just replace N with the number of observations in your dataset, and replace p with the true population probability that you want.

Comment: Since the dates are being randomly selected *from the dataset,* why are these distributional assumptions appropriate or helpful?  Why not just tally the data to obtain an exact, simple, correct answer?

Comment: @whuber I understood that the OP wanted to know the probability that 200 to 500 cases were in the sample of N observations by chance alone. I'll change that now.